# Pass a "parameter to a dynamic" JSP to JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

there is JSP file upLoad.jsp and popup_Tree.jsp, ViewTree.jsp
on page upLoad.jsp when you click on button`(value="...")`, opens popup`(ViewTree.jsp)`, which displays a directory tree, You can select the folder in which to save the file. On popup there is a button "Upload".

there is JSP file upLoad.jsp

```
<form name="fupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload file: <input type="f" name="f[]" id="filename" multiple="true" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" onClick="return buttonupload();"/>
<input type="button" value="..." onClick="top.popup_Show('/_additional/upload_Js/ViewTree', 300, 380);return false;void(0);"/>           
</form>
<% ...
String[] pathDir = request.getParameterValues("pathDir"); 
%>
```

popup_Tree.jsp

```
<% ...
String pathDir = getServletContext().getRealPath(dir);
%>
<form style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="dirPatch" id="dirPatch" value="<%=pathDir%>"/>
</form>
```

I want to convey the path `(from popup_Tree.jsp to upLoad.jsp)` where  will be saved file

I do so, convey meaning "the path to the folder":
popup_Tree.jsp -->

```
<% String pathDir = getServletContext().getRealPath(dir);%>
<form style="display:none;" name="f" metod="post" action= "/_additional/upload.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="dirPatch" id="dirPatch" value="<%= pathDir %>"/>
</form>
<%
    request.setAttribute("dirPtch", pathDir);
        String strViewPage="/_additional/upload.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(strViewPage);
        if (dispatcher != null){
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } 
%>
```

upLoad.jsp -->

```
<%
out.println(request.getAttribute("dirPtch"));
%>
```

BUT OUTPUT - Null

Answer (score 0):

You are posting a hidden form variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dirPatch" id="dirPatch" value="<%= pathDir %>"/>
```

So, on your `upload.jsp` you need to use [`getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)):

```
<% out.println(request.getParameter("dirPtch")); %>
```

Or, you could use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info):

```
${param.dirPtch}
```